# Changing variables in an infinite integral (is $\frac{1}{2}\left((dx)^{2}-(dy)^{2}\right)$ equivalent to $dxdy$)?

Tags: integration

If I have an integral of the form,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dxdye^{-i(ax+by)}f(x)g(y)dxdy
$$
where $\mathbb{R}$ represents the group of all real numbers, and i choose to change variables $$
q=x+y\text{,    }p=\frac{x-y}{2}
$$
can I write generally write the integral as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dxdye^{-i\left(a(\frac{1}{2}q+p)+b(\frac{1}{2}q-p)\right)}f(\frac{1}{2}q+p)g(\frac{1}{2}q-p)dpdq
$$
Intuitively,
$$
dqdp=\frac{1}{2}\left((dx)^{2}-(dy)^{2}\right)
$$
doesn't seem equivalent, however integrating over all values of $p,q$ does seem like it would reproduce all values of $x,y$. I only ask because in a derivation I'm following they appear to make this transformation (https://www.rug.nl/research/vsi/events/groenewold/groenewold-article.pdf, eq4.24 for reference)

Comment: What is $(dx)^2$ even supposed to mean?

Comment: Multivariable substitution requires the Jacobian of your transformation.

Comment: $dqdp=\frac{1}{2}(dx+dy)(dx-dy)=\frac{1}{2}dx\cdot dx+dy\cdot dx-dx\cdot dy-dy\cdot dy$ such that $(dx)^{2}=dx\cdot dx$ and $(dy)^{2}=dy\cdot dy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you are making is in how you interpret $dp dq$ as an ordinary multiplication of $(dx-dy)/2$ and $(dx+dy)$. Algebraic multiplication of differentials requires the wedge product, "$\wedge$", not ordinary multiplication.

One of the important properties of the wedge product is that anything wedged with itself is $0$ (similar to the cross product). This derives from the more general property that $\alpha \wedge \beta = - \beta \wedge \alpha$.

So,

$$ dp \wedge dq = (dx-dy)/2 \wedge (dx+dy)$$
$$ = (dx \wedge dx)/2 + (dx \wedge dy)/2 - (dy \wedge dx)/2 + (dy \wedge dy)/2 $$
$$ = dx \wedge dy.$$

Comment: ah I see, thanks I didn't realise this was a thing at all!